# Getting ViewModel for SettingsActivity (MVVM, Android P)

Tags: android, android-preferences, android-viewmodel, android-mvvm, viewmodelproviders

If you choose template with **Settings** creating a project in Androdi Studio 3.4, you will see example app with `SettingsActivity` extending `AppCompatPreferenceActivity` extending `PreferenceActivity` extending `ListActivity` extending `android.app.Activity`, but not the `FragmentActivity` which is necessary for creating a `ViewModel` for `SettingsActivity`by means of

```
SettingsViewModel viewModel

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    viewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this, viewModelFactory).get(SettingsViewModel.class);
}
```

because of `ViewModelProviders.of()` may accept only the `FragmentActivity` as a first argument.

Is it possible to create a `ViewModel` for `AppCompatPreferenceActivity` or it is the next reincarnation of hell with preferences from Google?!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This template has been completely redone in Android Studio 3.5 to match the [Settings documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/settings):

> The recommended way to integrate user configurable settings into your application is to use the AndroidX Preference Library. This library manages the user interface and interacts with storage so that you define only the individual settings that the user can configure. The library comes with a Material theme that provides a consistent user experience across devices and OS versions.

The [AndroidX Preferences Library](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/preference) does not require you to use `PreferenceActivity` at all - you'll note that it uses `AppCompatActivity` directly, putting preferences into a `PreferenceFragmentCompat`. As `AppCompatActivity` extends `FragmentActivity`, you will be able to use `ViewModel` and other AndroidX APIs without issue.